# Error being thrown when dealing with Stripe using @stripe/stripe-react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I've added Stripe into my React-Native/Expo (SDK 42) App. I am trying to make it so follow the "create payment" method laid out on stripes website, but it keeps throwing the following error:

```
undefined Unable to resolve module stripe from ../../../../.js stripe could not be found within the project.
```

I've tried calling Stripe, but I still keep getting the error.

Below is the code where the error lives:

```
import { CardField, useStripe, StripeProvider, Stripe } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native'

const stripe = require('stripe')('testKey')

const paymentMethod = async() => {
await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
    type: 'card',
    card:{
        number: '4242424242424242',
        exp_month: 9,
        exp_year: 2022,
        cvc: '314'
    }
})
```

}

I adapted this from the Node.js version found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create?lang=node)

Comment: Which version of `stripe-react-native` are you using?

Comment: @joachimwedin we're using "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.2.1" on Expo SDK 42

Comment: That code you've adapted is meant to be called server-side, and won't work with Stripe's React Native SDK. You want to be adapting the `stripe.createPaymentMethod()` call (https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method).

Comment: There's a quick example of how to use `createPaymentMethod` in the guide they have for folks that are migrating from the Tipsi library here (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/af261034f6c990217fdb39b8b702c128010d384a/docs/tipsi-stripe-migration-guide.md#paymentintent-api) in case it's helpful

Comment: @karbi I posted this on Reddit as well the other day and received the same reply, which makes me feel better, thank you. If you want the Stack credit, reply to this post and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you've included in your question is meant to be called server-side with Stripe's Node client library. It cannot be adapted to work client-side with the Stripe's React Native SDK.

Instead, you want to be calling the React Native equivalent of `stripe.createPaymentMethod()` (see JS library [ref](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method)). There's a quick example in the React Native library docs about how to do this [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/af261034f6c990217fdb39b8b702c128010d384a/docs/tipsi-stripe-migration-guide.md#paymentintent-api) (it was originally written for folks migrating from the Tipsi library, but it should also work for your use case).